# Inject new objects in for loop with CDI (Weld)

Tags: cdi, factory, inject, weld

I want to introduce CDI to existing project. Currently we are creating new objects inside for loop like

```
Context context;
for(String string : strings) {
    context = new Context();
    // do some operations with string.
    // set outcomes of above operation in context.
}
```

Now if I am injecting `Context` as

```
@Inject Context context;
```

I'm getting same instance every time.

I'm wondering if there is any way available in CDI to create new `Context` inside loop?

Comment: Why would you need that? You are trying to abuse the dependency injection mechanism.

Comment: Hi Adrian, do you think it would be a design approach. Although its a use case requirement, but before opting for it, I would definitely like to see if its a kind of anti pattern? Thanks, Raman

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you do not use special scopes, you can use

```
@Inject
Instance<B> bProvider;

...
B b = bProvider.get();
```

and you will get a new "B" everytime. Check out [this gist](https://gist.github.com/jangalinski/48fb703e45b977802d20).

Comment: To clarify, `B` must be annotated as `@Dependent` or not annotated at all in EE 6/7 (in 7 with bean discovery all)